# SharePoint Libraries not appearing

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

This is baffling me. I used PowerShell to add about 35 libraries to a site and then create and ADD 3 permissions groups for each library which are set to use unique permissions.

After running my code I thought all was fine. When I go to the site I see all the libraries that I made and can go into each of them and the permissions for each library are correct. However, if I go in as any other user I can't see any of the libraries. Even if I go to all "All Site Content" it's as if they don't exist.

I am the site collection admin and am part of that site's Owners group, but other people in the Owner's group can't see the libraries.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Does these library have their own permission settings instead of inheriting from the parent?

Comment: Yes they each have an owners group, members group, and readers group that were added through my script and the top level site owners group is the owner of all these groups. Each library's inheritance was broken before adding these groups.

Comment: Then I think this is because of no permission

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why or what permissions would be causing these libraries to just not appear at all on the top level site for anyone but me. The only permission I have over others who can't see them on the site is I was a site collection admin. I changed that and the new site collection admin can see the libraries now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that the other users who cannot see those library are not having any permission on that library,since you have broken inheritance. You can verify this by logging in as Site administrator. Open the document library--> Library settings-->Permissions for this document library --> Check Permissions. Here type in the user for whom the library was not available, then you can see if that user is actually having any permission on that library or not.

Comment: Okay, I agree this is the issue. I need to write a script to add the site admin as a member of each library's owners group. It's odd to me that if you are the owner of the permissions group you aren't inherently granted access to the library.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint, it has 5 permission level: full control, design, contribute, read, limit access. Permissions are categorized as list permissions, site permissions, and personal permissions, depending upon the objects to which they can be applied; and it can be inherited from the parent, or it can have its own. if one user doesn't have the permission to a list, the user can't see it.

Permissions control is complex in SharePoint, See these MSDN articles for details:

1. [Permission levels and permissions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-sharepoint-services-help/permission-levels-and-permissions-HA010100149.aspx)
2. [About controlling access to sites and site content](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-sharepoint-services-help/about-controlling-access-to-sites-and-site-content-HA010100144.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010100149)

Comment: Okay, I guess I was just under the assumption that the owner(in group settings) of the site permission groups I created would have access by default and not need to be added as a member of that group as well. I guess that's what I get for assuming.